# NullPointerException by sorting a list

Tags: java

is it possible to do the sort with a compareto Method I assign two variales, one of the typ Move4Connect and typ List?

Comment: Please post all the relevant code

Comment: make your question understanable.

Comment: Put debug point wherever you think the value will be null!! it will help you.

Comment: I did it.. when I print the list there is one element inside, but i I want to get coneccted to the list in my compare to method there is nothing in the list

Comment: Where exactly does the exception occur? The stack trace says it's on line 67, but There are only 30 or so lines in the class.

Comment: I cant' post the wohle code because it#s a study work. sorry

Comment: it's the first if statement in the compare to method          if(!columnsWithThreats.contains(compare.field.getColumn()) && columnsWithThreats.contains(this.field.getColumn())){

Comment: You should log-out/debug columnsWithThreats and members for "this" (log out this).

this.field belongs to the Move interface which we can't see.
Pretty sure this.field / compare.field is the problem

Comment: the problem is that the list columnsWithThreats is empty I want to sort the possibleMoves list

Answer (score 1):

Since you have said it is in the first `if` loop in `compareTo` method,

```
    if(!columnsWithThreats.contains(compare.field.getColumn()) &&       
    columnsWithThreats.contains(this.field.getColumn())){
                    return 1;
    }
```

I can utmost list down the possibilities of `nullpointerexception`

1) `columnsWithThreats` can be null

2) `compare` can be null

3) `compare.field` can be null

4) `this.field` can be null

If any of the above mentioned reference is null, that would cause `NullPointerException`. Hope this helps

Comment: I think the columnsWithsThreats is null, but the problem is that if I print the list befor I sort the possible List there is one integer in the list columns with threats but I don#T know why the list is emptywhen I take reference in the compareTo method

Comment: Try printing it just before this line `if(!columnsWithThreats.contains(compare.field.getColumn()) &&       
    columnsWithThreats.contains(this.field.getColumn())){`.

Comment: the size is 0, so ther is nothing inside

Comment: that shouldn't cause `NPE`, it will return 'false` when you check `contains`. Check the other variables for `null`

Comment: is it possible to do the sort with a compareto Method I assign two variales, one of the typ Move4Connect and typ List<Integer>?

Comment: I'm sorry. I couldn't understand your question

Comment: if there is the possibility to write the comperTo method like this: compareTo(Move4Connect compare, List<Integer> columnsWithThreats) {...}

Comment: No,you can't. you are actually implementing the abstract method from interface `Comparable`

Answer (score 0):

Your test calls your default

```
Game4Connect game = new Game4Connect();
```

which initializes columnsWithThreats but nothing else.
which means this.field for example is null and most likely compare.field as well.

You need to initialize all the member variables in your constructor meaning: !this! field